# Using a cell value in Google Sheets as an input to move a file from one folder to another using Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, typeerror

I have been researching the site but can't find the solution to my question. I a writing a script to extract a list of one or more filenames from a sheet and use these filenames as input to move the actual files from one folder to another in Drive. My issue now is that I don't know how to handle the value "Fileiterator" that is coming back in my script. As a result, the error I am getting when I run my script is "TypeError: Cannot find function makeCopy in object FileIterator"

I'm not sure if I am missing something when I am using the MakeCopy() method or setting up the variable pulling values from the sheet?

here is my code:

```
// Access Mailing List sheet in gdrive and get filename
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('spreadsheetURL'); 
var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
var value = sheet.getSheetValues(2,39,1,1);
Logger.log(value);
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("folderid1");
Logger.log(folder);
var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(value);
Logger.log(files);
var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById("folderid2");
Logger.log(destination);
newfile = files.makeCopy("copy of"+files,destination);
Logger.log(newfile);
```

Please advise!

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because `getFilesByName(name)` returns a FileIterator object but makeCopy is a File object method.

Example:

This shows how to use a file iterator.

```
var name = 'File name';
var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById("folderId");
var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName("File name");
while (files.hasNext()) {
  var file = files.next();
  file.makeCopy("copy of " + name, destination);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I think this clears up my confusion. I will modify the script and give you an update.